# Hi I want data from sql server after typing id in input field and click submit button in ASp.net core MVC 6

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have some student data like first Name, last Name, Hall Ticket Number, 5 subjects marks, total and percentage. This data is coming from Microsoft SQL Serve Management Studio. I want one input and one button if user enter Hall Ticket Number and click to button it will fetch the data from SQL Server and show all remaining detail of that student like first name, last name etc. in ASP.Net Core MVC.

I don't know what's wrong in my code. I don't want filter here.

```
@model IEnumerable<Result>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<div>
    <table id="tab" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Hall Ticket Number</th>
                <th>Subject 01</th>
                <th>Subject 02</th>
                <th>Subject 03</th>
                <th>Subject 04</th>
                <th>Subject 05</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var obj in Model)
            {
             <tr>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.fName</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.lName</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.hallTicketNum</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.sub1</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.sub2</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.sub3</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.sub4</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.sub5</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.total</td>
                 <td width="10%">@obj.percent</td>
             </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

```
@model IEnumerable<Result>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div class="mb-3">
    <input id="txtName" type="text" class="form-control" style="width:350px" placeholder="Enter HallTicket Number"/>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <button id="btnGet" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:350px">Submit</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       $("#btnGet").click(function(){
           var name = $("#txtName").val();
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/Result/Details",
             success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var name = $("#tab tbody");
                name.empty();
                $(data).each(function(id){
                    name.append("<tr><td>" + id.fName + "</td><td>" + id.lName + "</td><td>" + id.hallTicketNum + "</td><td>" + id.sub1 + "</td><td>" + id.sub2 + "</td><td>" + id.sub3 + "</td><td>" + id.sub4 + "</td><td>" + id.sub5 + "</td><td>" + id.total + "</td><td>" + id.percent + "</td></tr>");
                });
             },
             error: function(err){
                 alert(err);
             }
           });
       });
   })

</script>

<div>
    <table id="tab" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Hall Ticket Number</th>
                <th>Subject 01</th>
                <th>Subject 02</th>
                <th>Subject 03</th>
                <th>Subject 04</th>
                <th>Subject 05</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Here is the screenShots...
[Before Clicking submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6tRd.png)

[after clicking submit button without entering hallticket number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuC5A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(data).each(function(id){
    name.append("<tr><td>" + id.fName + "</td><td>" + id.lName + "</td><td>" + id.hallTicketNum + "</td><td>" + id.sub1 + "</td><td>" + id.sub2 + "</td><td>" + id.sub3 + "</td><td>" + id.sub4 + "</td><td>" + id.sub5 + "</td><td>" + id.total + "</td><td>" + id.percent + "</td></tr>");
});
```

to

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    name.append("<tr><td>" + item.fName + "</td><td>" + item.lName + "</td><td>" + item.hallTicketNum + "</td><td>" + item.sub1 + "</td><td>" + item.sub2 + "</td><td>" + item.sub3 + "</td><td>" + item.sub4 + "</td><td>" + item.sub5 + "</td><td>" + item.total + "</td><td>" + item.percent + "</td></tr>");
});
```